# How can i change the route link from a component with certain data

Tags: angular

I'm working on an angular project and I'm currently displaying a list of accounts( data received from api). What I want to do is if the user press on one line( each line represent an account) he gets redirected to another page but in the URL he can find the account id he pressed.
I mean if the user just has the link and modify the account id he should be able to see it directly.
Maybe this example can help

List of accounts id

```js
[-3211, -3212, -3213]
```

The URL to the displaying accounts is 'localhost/accounts' and when he press one account he gets redirected to another page and the link modifies to 'localhost/accounts/3211'

I tried adding some variables to the path in app routing but is not working maybe because I don't use correctly the variable.

```js
{
    path: 'accounts' + id,
    component: AccountsComponent
}
```

Comment: what if you use dynamic route parameters? for example `accounts/:id`? and your path will be `accounts/3211-3212-3213`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route:

```
 { path: 'accounts/:id', component: AccountsComponent },
```

Navigation inside parent component on click:

```
this.route.navigateByUrl(`/accounts/${id}`).then();
```

Inside child component to get the id (so u could call account details for example):

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
}
```